# Getting WA in ANUGCD from Codechef March Long Contest

Tags: c++, testcase, sieve, rmq

I am Getting WA in the Question **GCD Condition** from **Codechef March Long Contest**.
Kindly tell me what I've done wrong or some test case where the code produces Wrong answer.

[***Link for the Question***](http://www.codechef.com/MARCH14/problems/ANUGCD)

I Have used RMQ(Range maximum Query) for every prime number

```
for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
{
    int sz=b[i].size();
    if(!sz)continue;
    int level=0;
    cc[i].resize(sz);
    for(j=0;j<sz;j++)cc[i][j].push_back(b[i][j]);//level 0
    for(level=1;(1<<level)<=sz;level++)
    {
        for(j=0;j+(1<<level)<=sz;j++)
        {
            int c1=cc[i][j][level-1];
            int c2=cc[i][j+(1<<(level-1))][level-1];
            int mx=(a[c1]<a[c2])?c2:c1;
            cc[i][j].push_back(mx);
        }
    }
}
```

---

firstly i have converted to a structure like the following:-

Example input:- 10 6 20 15 8

(b[i]-->stores the indices of factors of i)
b[2]--> 1,2,3,5
b[3]--> 2,4
b[5]--> 1,3,4

Now after implementing RMQ, it will be as follow:-

(cc[i][j][k] stores index of the largest element between b[i][j] and b[i][j+(2^k)-1])
cc[2][0]-->1,2,3,5 
cc[2][1]-->1,3,3
cc[2][2]-->3

cc[3][0]-->2,4
cc[3][1]-->4

cc[5][0]-->1,3,4
cc[5][1]-->3

---

[My Code](http://ideone.com/ut4Ikj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 1
88 33 23 56 97 54 8 74 43 95 91 63 38 13 7 7 52 29 6 85 70 15 52 18 78 9 85 51 28 43 4 68 75 78 75 23 32 34 48 74 28 90 36 66 2 95 24 54 23 29 90 45 96 93 14 73 2 99 75 81 93 31 100 19 8 75 93 39 60 41 64 88 30 100 5 84 46 28 89 20 56 30 64 3 22 78 75 75 76 2 8 20 32 7 38 39 33 82 30 93
95 95 97

The output is **-1 -1**, but gcd(38, 95) = 19, so ans should be **38 1**.

> **Replacing 'break' by 'continue' on line 75 gave AC :)**